# MVC + Templates

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a system that gets templatse dynamicly, they contain tags like {{SomeUserControl}} {{SomeContent}}

I was wonder how I could use MVC to render those templates and replacing the tags in the best possible way as the templates will be edited via a web front end, and the content / macros will be create from the same web front end.

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna take a look at maybe using another view engine, here are some examples.

[NHaml](http://andrewpeters.net/2007/12/19/introducing-nhaml-an-aspnet-mvc-view-engine/)
[Spark](http://dev.dejardin.org/)
[NVelocity](http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/)
[Brail](http://www.castleproject.org/monorail/documentation/v1rc2/viewengines/brail/index.html)

I'm sure there are many more but these are the ones I could think of.